# Using no cache in jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I have this GET in jQuery Ajax and I need to convert it to Fetch. The question I'm having is that `cache: false` is the same as `cache: "no-store"` in header param in fetch?
Ajax call

```
function ajaxLogoutDetailsApi() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "OIDCGetLogoutDetails",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    data: "json",
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
      data = data.replace('\/\*', '');
      data = data.replace('\*\/', '');
      var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
      if (dataJson.logoutUrl != null) {
        document.location.href = dataJson.logoutUrl;
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, err) {
      console.log("error in ajaxLogoutDetailsApi");
    }
  });
}
```

Fetch call:

```
function ajaxLogoutDetailsApi() {
  
  const endpoint = 'OIDCGetLogoutDetails';
  
  fetch(endpoint, {cache: "no-store"})
    .then(json => {
      const updated = json
        .replace('\/\*', '')
        .replace('\*\/', '');
      const data = JSON.parse(updated);
      if (data.logoutUrl) {
        window.location.href = data.logoutUrl;
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });

}
```

Comment: No, they're not the same. Just compare https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache

Comment: Btw, `cache: "no-store"` is **not** a header in the `fetch` API

Comment: @Bergi I understand, so what would be the correspondent in fetch API ? As I posted, I need to convert that Ajax to Fetch

Comment: Use `cache: "no-cache"`. It's the closest to jquery's `cache: false`.

Comment: @ruleboy21 I will try with ``cache: "no-cache"``` thanks!

Comment: @Besworks There are several opinions.. I think I will try with ```cache: "no-cache"``` instead of ```cache: "no-store"```. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> `cache` (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp') Type:
> Boolean
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
> browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with
> HEAD and GET requests. **It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the
> GET parameters**. The parameter is not needed for other types of
> requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already
> been requested by a GET.

Comment: So what correspondent this ```cache: false``` from ajax have in Fetch API ? ```cache: no cache``` ?